# Error al ejecutar 'createObjectURL' en 'URL':

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web que lea código qr, cuando la ejecuto me aparece este error:

> *Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.*

He probado varias librerías js para leer código qr y con todas aparece ese error.

Estoy usando la libreria `WebCodeCam.js`

Este es el código en donde marca el error.

```
cameraSuccess: function(stream) {
    streams[Self.options.videoSource.id] = stream;
    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    camera.src = url ? url.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
    camera.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigando, ya que nadie fue capaz de ayudarme encontre que el método `createObjectURL`
es obsoleto en las nuevas versiones de los navegadores, y lo que hice fue cambiar el código asi.

```
cameraSuccess: function(stream) {
    streams[Self.options.videoSource.id] = stream;
    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    try {
       camera.srcObject = stream;
    } catch (error) {
       camera.src = url.createObjectURL(stream);
    } finally{ 
       camera.play();
    }      
}
```